# Why does collectionView.scrollToItem scrolls indexPath outside of view using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

The following function loads an array of `Messages`, reloads the `collectionView` and (should) scroll to the last item.

**The problem is that the last item scrolls too far up past and outside the view so it is not visible.**

Note: I am using 3 different "prototype" auto-sizing cells  which are dequeued depending on the type of message (text message, image message, etc..).

It seems like such a simple task, but I'm starting to pull my hair over this one. Any help would be great :)

```
func loadConversation(){


    DataService.run.observeUsersMessagesFor(forUserId: chatPartnerId!) { (chatLog) in
        self.messages = chatLog
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        if self.messages.count > 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom , animated: true)
        }


    }

}//end func
```

EDIT: numberOfItemsInSection function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return messages.count

    }
```

EDIT: cellForItemAt

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let message = messages[indexPath.item]

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        if message.fromId == uid {

            if message.imageUrl != nil {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ConversationCellImage", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCellImage
                cell.configureCell(message: message)
                return cell

            } else {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ConversationCellSender", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCellSender
                cell.configureCell(message: message)
                return cell

            }//end if message.imageUrl != nil


        } else {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ConversationCell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCell
            cell.configureCell(message: message)
            return cell

        }//end if 

    }//end func
```

EDIT: `ConversationCell` `Class` which auto-sizes the height of the cell.

```
class ConversationCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var chatPartnerProfileImg: CircleImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLbl: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        chatPartnerProfileImg.isHidden = false

    }//end func

    func configureCell(message: Message){

        messageLbl.text = message.message

        let partnerId = message.chatPartnerId()

        DataService.run.getUserInfo(forUserId: partnerId!) { (user) in
            let url = URL(string: user.profilePictureURL)
            self.chatPartnerProfileImg.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload], completed: nil)

        }//end getUserInfo

    }//end func


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 10.0)
        self.clipsToBounds = false

    }//end func



    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        //toggles auto-layout
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()

        //Tries to fit contentView to the target size in layoutAttributes
        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)

        //Update layoutAttributes with height that was just calculated
        var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
        frame.size.height = ceil(size.height) + 18
        layoutAttributes.frame = frame
        return layoutAttributes
    }



}//end class
```

Comment: Show `numberOfRows` delegate please.

Comment: I haven't define `numberOfRows`, I have only defined `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAt`

Comment: Yes `numberOfItemsInSection` is what i meant. My bad. Can you share that code?

Comment: I have edited my question, see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the UI related tasks on the main thread. Update your function loadConversation as per follows

```
func loadConversation() {
DataService.run.observeUsersMessagesFor(forUserId: chatPartnerId!) { (chatLog) in
    self.messages = chatLog
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

    if self.messages.count > 0 {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
        // set animated false/true, based on the new messages. if many new messages keep it false
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom , animated: true)
    }
  }
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

The flickering is due to the userImage being set. It should be on main thread.
Update it to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.chatPartnerProfileImg.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload], completed: nil)
}
```

Try and share the results.

Comment: No, the message cells are still being scrolled way too far to the top off of the screen. Perhaps there is an issues with auto-sizing?

Comment: I did change `animated: true` from your answer which causes the same issue, but when I change back to `animated: false` the issue goes away and it scrolls to bottom as expected... I would really like it if it was animated, what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: I have edited my question to include a short gif which shows the chat log (collectionView) loaded with messages, last message being scrolled to, but the issue is that when I scroll up there is a flickering which prevents cells to move up.

Comment: did you see the gif i posted?

Comment: Yes. why to check every time for the current user  userId in cell, declare it as a variable on top like var uid: String! and in viewDidLoad put, uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

Comment: Flickering effect is may be due to the code in configureCell part, please post that too.

Comment: I have included `ConversationCell` class (above) which dequeues a text message, there are other similar classes that dequeues other message types eg; image. Also, your suggestion to move `uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` did have no effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177715/discussion-between-bhavin-kansagara-and-roggie).

Comment: Bhavin, this hasn't actually solved my issue, I have raised another question in the hope of getting further assistance. I believe this issue appears to be with the loading of the cells..
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777827/my-uicollectionview-does-not-scroll-smoothly-using-swift