# My UICollectionView does not scroll smoothly using Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `CollectionView` which dequeues a cell depending on the `message` type (eg; text, image).

The problem I am having is that when I scroll up/down **the scroll is really choppy and thus not a very good user experience.** This only happens the first time the cells are loaded, after that the scrolling is smooth.

**Any ideas how I can fix this?, could this be an issue with the time its taking to fetch data before the cell is displayed?**

I am not too familiar with running tasks on background threads etc. and not sure what changes I can make to prefect the data pre/fetching etc.. please help!

The Gif shows scroll up when the view loads, it shows the cells/view being choppy as I attempt to scroll up.

[image]

This is my `func loadConversation()` which loads the `messages` array

```
func loadConversation(){

        DataService.run.observeUsersMessagesFor(forUserId: chatPartnerId!) { (chatLog) in
            self.messages = chatLog
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

                if self.messages.count > 0 {
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)

                    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom , animated: false)

                }
            }
        }//observeUsersMessagesFor

    }//end func
```

This is my cellForItemAt which dequeues cells

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let message = messages[indexPath.item]

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


        if message.fromId == uid {

            if message.imageUrl != nil {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ConversationCellImage", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCellImage
                cell.configureCell(message: message)
                return cell

            } else {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ConversationCellSender", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCellSender
                cell.configureCell(message: message)
                return cell

            }//end if message.imageUrl != nil


        } else {

            if message.imageUrl != nil {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ConversationCellImageSender", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCellImageSender
                cell.configureCell(message: message)
                return cell

            } else {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ConversationCell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCell
            cell.configureCell(message: message)
            return cell

            }

        }//end if uid 

    }//end func
```

This is my `ConversationCell` class which configures a custom cell for dequeueing by `cellForItemAt` (note: in addition there another `ConversationCellImage` custom cell class which configures an image message):

```
class ConversationCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var chatPartnerProfileImg: CircleImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLbl: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()


        chatPartnerProfileImg.isHidden = false

    }//end func

    func configureCell(message: Message){

        messageLbl.text = message.message

        let partnerId = message.chatPartnerId()


        DataService.run.getUserInfo(forUserId: partnerId!) { (user) in
            let url = URL(string: user.profilePictureURL)
            self.chatPartnerProfileImg.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload], completed: nil)

        }//end getUserInfo


    }//end func


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 10.0)
        self.clipsToBounds = false

    }//end func

    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

//toggles auto-layout
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()

        //Tries to fit contentView to the target size in layoutAttributes
        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)

        //Update layoutAttributes with height that was just calculated
        var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
        frame.size.height = ceil(size.height) + 18
        layoutAttributes.frame = frame
        return layoutAttributes
    }

}//end class
```

Time Profile results:

[image]

Edit: Flowlayout code

```
if let flowLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout,
    let collectionView = collectionView {
    let w = collectionView.frame.width - 40
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: w, height: 200)
}// end if-let
```

Edit: `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` function in my custom cell class

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    //toggles auto-layout
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()

    //Tries to fit contentView to the target size in layoutAttributes
    let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)

    //Update layoutAttributes with height that was just calculated
    var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
    frame.size.height = ceil(size.height) + 18
    layoutAttributes.frame = frame
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
extension ConversationVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var height: CGFloat = 80

        let message = messages[indexPath.item]

        if let text = message.message {

            height = estimateFrameForText(text).height + 20

        } else if let imageWidth = message.imageWidth?.floatValue, let imageHeight = message.imageHeight?.floatValue{

            height = CGFloat(imageHeight / imageWidth * 200)

        }

        let width = collectionView.frame.width - 40

        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    fileprivate func estimateFrameForText(_ text: String) -> CGRect {
        let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)

    }

}//end extension
```

Comment: is there any api call in your cell ??

Comment: I have pasted the code to my custom `ConversationCell` class above on my original question, the only call being made is to load the image via `sd_setImage`, but this happens even if there are no images to load. I also have the `loadConversation()` function which fetches the data from Firebase through a singleton class method called

Comment: Profile your app using the time profiler. It will show which code is taking long. You have lots of code in odd places. Like setting your shadow... that should be in awake from nib not layout sub views etc... and that “toggle autolayout” thing looks dodgy... why are you doing that?

Comment: First time I have ran a Time Profiler on any app, what am should I be looking for? how can I share my results?

Comment: @Fogmeister I have edited my question to include a screenshot of my Time Profile results and I can see that the custom cells to load the chat are some of the biggest culprits. I just don't know how I can use to address my issue?

Comment: @Fogmeister I've removed all the my custom `collectionViewLayout` for self-sizing cells and that has stopped the choppiness when scrolling. Are you able to point me in the right direction to adding proper self-sizing cells to a collection view?

Comment: @Fogmeister I managed to solve my issue, I have updated my question with an edit which includes my solution and the complete `sizeForItemAt` as well as an `estimateFrameForText` function. I really appreciate your help, it really assisted me in solving my issue.

Comment: select UICollectionview in IB and uncheck Paging Enabled.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, let's try finding the exact location where this problem is arising.

**Try 1:**

comment this line

```
//self.chatPartnerProfileImg.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload], completed: nil)
```

And run your app to see the results.

**Try 2:**

Put that line in async block to see the results.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.chatPartnerProfileImg.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload], completed: nil)
}
```

**Try 3:** Comment the code for setting corner radius

```
/*self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 10.0)
        self.clipsToBounds = false*/
```

Share your results for Try 1, 2 and 3 and then we can get the better idea about where the problem lies.

Hope this way we can get the reason behind flickering.

Comment: I have tried all three of your suggestions and I get the same issue. The strange thing is that once the cells have loaded the scrolling is smooth.

Comment: I have been able to point-point what is causing the choppiness. I commented out all my `collectioViewFlowLayout` from my code and it now scrolls smoothly. But now I need to figure out how to add cell-autosizing to my app so the cells height autosizes.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure that the data like image or GIF shouldn't download on the main thread.

This is the reason why your scrolling is not smooth. Download the data in separate thread in background use either GCD or NSOperation queue. Then show the downloaded image always on main thread.

use AlamofireImage pods, it will automatically handle the downloaded task in background.

```
import AlamofireImage

extension UIImageView {

func downloadImage(imageURL: String?, placeholderImage: UIImage? = nil) {
    if let imageurl = imageURL {
        self.af_setImage(withURL: NSURL(string: imageurl)! as URL, placeholderImage: placeholderImage) { (imageResult) in
            if let img = imageResult.result.value {
                self.image = img.resizeImageWith(newSize: self.frame.size)
                self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            }
        }
    } else {
        self.image = placeholderImage
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your response, I am not too familiar about running tasks in background vs main threads. Are you able to elaborate? or perhaps show what changes to my code are required?

Comment: I am using SDWebImage to load my images asynchronously and I believe it uses GCD and ARC (according to the their GitHub page), what is the difference?

Comment: Image caching, AlamofireImage is done image caching itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the choppiness you are seeing is because the cells are given a size and then override the size they were given which causes the layout to shift around. What you need to do is do the calculation during the creation of the layout first time through.

I have a function that I have used like this...

```
func height(forWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    // do the height calculation here
}
```

This is then used by the layout to determine the correct size first time without having to change it.

You could have this as a static method on the cell or on the data... or something.

What it needs to do is create a cell (not dequeue, just create a single cell) then populate the data in it. Then do the resizing stuff. Then use that height in the layout when doing the first layout pass.

Yours is choppy because the collection lays out the cells with a height of 20 (for example) and then calculates where everything needs to be based on that... then you go... "actually, this should be 38" and the collection has to move everything around now that you've given it a different height. This then happens for every cell and so causes the choppiness.

I might be able to help a bit more if I could see your layout code.

**EDIT**

Instead of using that `preferredAttributes` method you should implement the delegate method `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`.

Do something like this...

This method goes into the view controller.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    let height: CGFloat

    if let url = message.imageURL {
        height = // whatever height you want for the images
    } else {
        height = // whatever height you want for the text
    }

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - 40, height: height)
}
```

You may have to add to this but it will give you an idea.

Once you've done this... remove all your code from the cell to do with changing the frames and attributes etc.

Also... put your shadow code into the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: I have added my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` code in my VC and my `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` code from my custom cell `class`

Comment: @Roggie I've updated with a better way of getting the correct heights of items.

Comment: I have made your suggested changes with some test height CGFloat values of 100 for now..the cells are not displaying at all and I am getting a tone of non-stop console errors like: `The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2018-08-10 21:56:18.142459+0930 vipeeps[12101:5937397] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2018-08-10 21:56:18.142518+0930 vipeeps[12101:5937397] Please check the values returned by the delegate.`

Comment: @Roggie take a look at the error :D The width of the cell must be smaller than the width of the collection view minus the section insets. So I maybe got the width wrong. Try using a different calculation for the width. You can get the width of the collection view and the size section insets from the `collectionView` and `collectionViewLayout` passed into the function. I'd suggest using `guard let flowLayout = layout as? UICollectionVIewFloaLayout else { return .zero }` at the beginning and then use the section insets from the flowLayotu.

Comment: this is all new to me and I'm trying to get my head around it :) my section insets are top: 4, bottom: 4, left/right: 0 in the story board so I thought that my cell is `collectionView.frame.width - 40` which is less than the width of my collectionview :/

Comment: @Roggie Hmm... should be. Try a small size like 50 or 100 or something. Also... try `print(flowLayout.sectionInset)` ... not sure if correct syntax. But do that in the delegate function. They might be different from what you expect.

Comment: that didnt work either, i'll have to work out the correct width. The syntax to print out the sectionInsets did not work either.